# change footer size by id

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to run a function that changes the margin-top size according to what is being displayed. However, it doesn't seem to be working?

```
<body onload="changeFooter()">

<script>

const heading = document.getElementById('verify'); 
const footer = document.getElementById('footer')


function changeFooter () {
   if (heading == true){
       footer.style.marginTop = "200px"
   }
}
```

also tried this

```
function changeFooter () {
   if (heading.match('Verify')){
       footer.style.marginTop = "200px"
   }
}



</script>


 <h1 id="verify" class="verifyheading">Verify Identity</h1>
```

Thank you

Comment: try `if (heading) {}` - you don't need the `== true` as it's an object so it won't be true if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns the element (if it exists) or null, not a boolean (true/false).

You can simply do `if(heading) { ... }`  as your condition.

Here's a snippet based on your code: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/XWZVqWx

Comment: hmm, it's quite strange, I tried that before I had the same issue. Nothing is happening on my side.  Could there be something blocking the code from running ? console.log is clean.

Comment: Please provide a codepen / codesandbox with your full code if you think there is still a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Let put line code of `<h1>` before your `script` tag, `heading` will null if not define yet:

```html
<body onload="changeFooter()">

 <h1 id="verify" class="verifyheading">Verify Identity</h1>
 <div id="footer">Footer with marginTop</div>

<script>

const heading = document.getElementById('verify'); 
const footer = document.getElementById('footer')


function changeFooter () {
   if (heading){
       footer.style.marginTop = "200px"
   }
}

</script>
```